# FATAL miktex-makefmt - miktex-pdftex.exe failed on pdflatex.ini

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texstudio, windows, miktex2.9

I had an error with l3backend. After spending too much time trying and failing, I decided to re-install MiKTeX2.9. Now the error changed to pdflatex not succeed. I searched again and tried and failed again. Here are some things that I tried but doesn't work. Now, I forget about the l3backend problem and want my MiKTeX back working. Note that I am using windows 10.

- Clean uninstall MiKTeX.
- Re-install TexStudio.
- Re-install using admin for all-users
- Re-install for the current user only on C:\MiKTeX2.9
- Build format for pdflatex using MiKTeX Console.
- Refresh FNDB, Font Maps, and Packages Database.
- Update MiKTeX2.9 to the latest version.
- Restart the window, enter commands in the terminal.

None of these solve the problem, and I still can not build my latex project.

[Here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AumuKAHot2yOjE8fCCJr_HxlfBbc?e=4X45kl) are the log files of my MiKTeX.

Comment: Stop installing and reinstalling, try at first to get some clue what is wrong. As a first step: Run in a command line pointing to some test folder `miktex-pdftex.exe  --initialize  --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini`. If it errors type x and enter. It should create a log-file (pdflatex.log) in this folder. Show this log-file.

Comment: I enter the command in user mode (not admin), and it just finished without asking to press any key. The log files are [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AumuKAHot2yOjFDRUN1ny1p_HAd0?e=nwp0uE). It consists of two files generated by the command and one file that is the output of the command, copied from CMD (terminal).